# Creating new columns using for loop based on logical expression in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1 ['TG'] = [0,2,1,3,5,7,]
df1['Value'] =[0.2,0.5,0.015,0.6,0.11,0.12]
```

I wanted to create new columns based on the value of TG columns (i.e. <1,<2,<3,<4 and >0,>1,>2,>3 etc.)

The column names will be U0.5,U1.5,U2.5,U3.5, O0.5,O1.5,O2.5,O3.5. Thus, I will have 8 new columns with the above-mention column names. Value for each cell will be from **Value** columns. My expected output will be as follows:

[image]

I could use np.where to create a new column at a time.

How can I do it in a loop?

Comment: What is number of rows and number of new columns in real DataFrame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use numpy broadcasting, so no loop necessary:

```
#create array
arr = np.arange(1, 5) - .5
print (arr)
[0.5 1.5 2.5 3.5]

#create Mx1 arrays from Series
vals = df1['Value'].values[:, None]
tg = df1['TG'].values[:, None]

#compare arrays and multiple, use DataFrame constructor
df2 = pd.DataFrame((arr > tg) * vals, columns=arr).add_prefix('U')
df3 = pd.DataFrame((arr < tg) * vals, columns=arr).add_prefix('O')

#join all together
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1)
print (df)  
   TG  Value  U0.5   U1.5   U2.5   U3.5   O0.5  O1.5  O2.5  O3.5
0   0  0.200   0.2  0.200  0.200  0.200  0.000  0.00  0.00  0.00
1   2  0.500   0.0  0.000  0.500  0.500  0.500  0.50  0.00  0.00
2   1  0.015   0.0  0.015  0.015  0.015  0.015  0.00  0.00  0.00
3   3  0.600   0.0  0.000  0.000  0.600  0.600  0.60  0.60  0.00
4   5  0.110   0.0  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.110  0.11  0.11  0.11
5   7  0.120   0.0  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.120  0.12  0.12  0.12
```

Loop solution:

```
arr = np.arange(1, 5) - .5
for x in arr:
    df1[f"U{x}"] = df1["Value"] * (df1["TG"] < x)
for x in arr:
    df1[f"O{x}"] = df1["Value"] * (df1["TG"] > x)

print (df1)
   TG  Value  U0.5   U1.5   U2.5   U3.5   O0.5  O1.5  O2.5  O3.5
0   0  0.200   0.2  0.200  0.200  0.200  0.000  0.00  0.00  0.00
1   2  0.500   0.0  0.000  0.500  0.500  0.500  0.50  0.00  0.00
2   1  0.015   0.0  0.015  0.015  0.015  0.015  0.00  0.00  0.00
3   3  0.600   0.0  0.000  0.000  0.600  0.600  0.60  0.60  0.00
4   5  0.110   0.0  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.110  0.11  0.11  0.11
5   7  0.120   0.0  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.120  0.12  0.12  0.12
```

Comment: Thanks Jez. I remember one of your solution that you advised me in other post. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi Jez, If you can spare just 5 to 10 min, I like to ask something related to python. is it ok?

Comment: @Zephyr - sure, come on

Comment: I was trying to use the following code to manipulate the data
L = [1,2,3,4]
for v in L:
    #new column name 
    col = 'HG>={}'.format(v)
    #filter by condition
    df1 =  df[df['HomeGoal'] >= v]
    #new Series filled by aggregated values per groups and added column AOS
    df[col] = df1.groupby('Match')['%Prob'].transform('sum') #+ df['AOS']
    #only first non missing value per group
    mask = ~df.dropna(subset=[col]).duplicated(subset=[col, 'Match']) 
    df[col] = df[col].mask(~mask, 0)
it shows some error as follow:


ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: How can we go into chat box?

Comment: @Zephyr - no idea, but I try find it

Comment: By the way, I have your e-mail, do you mind if I send via e-mail?

Comment: @Zephyr - in my profile, only run code. Then please sent me some sample data too :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191890/discussion-between-zephyr-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 1):

if you still want a loop, there's one easy and elegant way to do it:

```py
l = [0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5]
for item in l:
    df1["U" + str(item)] = df1["Value"] * (df1["TG"] < item)
    df1["O" + str(item)] = df1["Value"] * (df1["TG"] > item)
```

Output is:

```
TG  Value   U0.5    O0.5    U1.5    O1.5    U2.5    O2.5    U3.5    O3.5
0   0   0.200   0.2 0.000   0.200   0.00    0.200   0.00    0.200   0.00
1   2   0.500   0.0 0.500   0.000   0.50    0.500   0.00    0.500   0.00
2   1   0.015   0.0 0.015   0.015   0.00    0.015   0.00    0.015   0.00
3   3   0.600   0.0 0.600   0.000   0.60    0.000   0.60    0.600   0.00
4   5   0.110   0.0 0.110   0.000   0.11    0.000   0.11    0.000   0.11
5   7   0.120   0.0 0.120   0.000   0.12    0.000   0.12    0.000   0.12
```

You just then need to re-arrange the column order